# Split using delimiter except when delimiter is escaped

Tags: c#, excel, string, clipboard

I'm reading clipboard data coming from excel using

`var stream = (System.IO.Stream) ( Forms.Clipboard.GetDataObject() ).GetData( Forms.DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue );`,

but unfortunately, excel is passing cell text instead of cell values. When the cells are using special formatting (such as the thousands seperator), the clipboard data for a series of cells in columns that looks like this:

```
 1,234,123.00    2,345.00    342.00      12,345.00
```

is stored as this:

```
\" 1,234,123.00 \",\" 2,345.00 \", 342.00 ,\" 12,345.00 \"
```

when what I really want is this:

```
 1234123.00, 2345.00, 342.00, 12345.00
```

I had been previously using the `clipData.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSllitOptions.None))` function to turn my CSV clipboard data into a series of cells, but this fails when there is escaped formatted text containing commas.

---

I'm asking if anyone can think of a way to split this string into a set of cells, ignoring the commas escaped within the `\"` bits, since this is how Excel is choosing to escape cells containing commas.

In short, how can I turn a single string containing this:

```
\" 1,234,123.00 \",\" 2,345.00 \", 342.00 ,\" 12,345.00 \"
```

into an array of strings containing this:

```
{ "1,234,123.00", "2,345.00", "342.00", "12,345.00" }
```

Without ruining my ability to parse a simple comma delimited string.

*****edit***

Follow up question (formulated as a DFA) here: [Split a string based on each time a Deterministic Finite Automata reaches a final state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462168/split-a-string-based-on-each-time-a-deterministic-finite-automata-reaches-a-final)

Comment: Are you actually seeing a \ followed by a " or are you just using \" to indicate a double quote instead of a denotation of the beginning of a string.

Comment: Can't you get the data in another format? Use IDataObject.GetFormats to retrieve a list of available formats and see if you can find one that works better.

Comment: Alright I'm going to take my time evaluating and testing several of these solutions and get back to you guys.

Comment: Many of the solutions fail due to the fact that excel does not always put quotation marks around the cell values, only when they contain a comma. Any case using "split" that would dodge accidentally splitting commas within quotation marks would fail to correctly split on commas when quotes are not used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off I've dealt with data from Excel before and what you typically see is comma separated values and if the value is considered to be a string it will have double quotes around it (and can contain commas and double quotes).  If it is considered to be numeric then there are not double quotes.  Additionally if the data contains a double quote that will be delimited by a double quote like `""`.  So assuming all of that here's how I've dealt with this in the past

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitExcelRow(this string value)
{
    value = value.Replace("\"\"", "&quot;");
    bool quoted = false;
    int currStartIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
    {
        char currChar = value[i];
        if (currChar == '"')
        {
            quoted = !quoted;       
        }
        else if (currChar == ',')
        {
            if (!quoted)
            {
                yield return value.Substring(currStartIndex, i - currStartIndex)
                    .Trim()
                    .Replace("\"","")
                    .Replace("&quot;","\"");
                currStartIndex = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    yield return value.Substring(currStartIndex, value.Length - currStartIndex)
        .Trim()
        .Replace("\"", "")
        .Replace("&quot;", "\"");
}
```

Of course this assumes the data coming in is valid so if you have something like `"fo,o"b,ar","bar""foo"` this will not work.  Additionally if your data contains `&quot;` then it will be turned into a " which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: It gets worse if you are dealing with a csv dump from Excel because rows are delimited by newlines, but a cell can contain a newline and you have to see if the newline is "quoted" to determine if it is part of the data or the beginning of a new row.

Comment: This is the best approach given here, because when it comes to splitting strings by commas, unless they are surrounded by quotation marks, what is really required is an iterative implementation of the deterministic finite automata corresponding to this problem. While regular expressions can validate whether a string satisfies a DFA, I'm not aware of it being able to split strings based on each instance of the final state being satisfied. Hence, a manual evaluation of the DFA by iteration. Cheers.

Comment: Follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462168/split-a-string-based-on-each-time-a-deterministic-finite-automata-reaches-a-final

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this. One inelegant way that would work is:

1. Convert \",\" to tab or some other delimiter (I assume you left out a few \" in your example because otherwise the string is not consistent
2. Strip all remaining commas
3. Strip all remaining \"
4. Convert your delimiter (e.g. tab) back into a comma

Now you have what you wanted in first place

Comment: Why substitute \",\" with something else when you can just split on that.  Also I know from experience that Excel does not always put double quotes around data, so there is a potential for something like `\"1,234\",123,\"2,345\"`.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I was splitting on `"` but didn't want to split on `\"` so I replaced all `\"` with something crazy that would never be there, and then split it by `"` and the replaced the crazy stuff with `\"` after the split. Worked great!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kyle regarding your string probably not being consistent.

Instead of Kyle's first step you could use

```
string[] vals = Regex.Split(value, @"\s*\"",\s*");
```

Comment: although now you have two problems :)

Comment: @Nat that is an inappropriate joke and an incorrect joke too. Firstly people might not be aware that you are repeating a joke that if you consider solving something with a regular expression you then have two problems. i.e. you're not saying there is any problem with his solution. So your joke is inappropriate here as it could be misinterpreted by those not familiar with it. Secondly, once you have a solution from the regex, you no longer have two problems, if it works you kind of have 0 problems, so your joke is also wrong in this context or any context where you have the solution..

Answer (score 0):

From your input example, we can see that there are three "unwanted" sequences of characters:

```
\"
\",
,\"
```

So, add all these sequences to the input array for the `Split` method:

```
string[] result = clipData.Split(new[] { @",\""", @"\"",", @"\""" }, 
    StringSplitOptions.None);
```

This will give you an array containing a few empty elements. If that is a problem, use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` instead of `StringSplitOptions.None`:

```
string[] result = clipData.Split(new[] { @",\""", @"\"",", @"\""" }, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: That would then split on the thousand separator within the number as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is the potential for the input to be `123 , 456 , 789` as Excel only puts the double quotes around data that is considered a string (in this case when the data contains a comma).  In that case your solution would not work.

Comment: @juharr: you may very well be correct. Sometimes I get the feeling that as soon as data is touched by Excel, all bets are off, and you need to be prepared for just about anything.

Comment: Yeah, as juharr pointed out, this is complicated by the fact that escape characters are only used when the cell contains a comma, otherwise everything is normally comma delimited.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a bit of LINQ:

```
string excelData = "\\\" 1,234,123.00 \\\",\\\" 2,345.00 \\\", 342.00 ,\\\" 12,345.00 \\\"";

IEnumerable<string> cells = from x in excelData.Split(new string[] { "\\\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                            let y = x.Trim(',').Trim()
                            where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y)
                            select y;
```

Alternatively, if you don't like this suggestion, try to implement a similar pattern with RegEx.